# XDG0062 Type Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView2 cannot be created in XAML

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, webview2, winui

I have a [UWP project](https://github.com/BSVN/linphone-windows10) and using WebView2 like below

[image]

My project is correctly build and run and behavior of my project is correct, but Visual Studio says below error

[image]

**My question is How to resolve this problem? (How to fix this errors?)**

Note: I post similar question to [Microsoft Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/XDG0062-Type-MicrosoftUIXamlControls/10081031) to ensure that is bug or not?

Comment: I tried to test directly with the github sample you shared but failed due to lacking some SDK. I created a blank UWP project to test, the error did show when I first added the webview2 control to the Xaml, but after I build and run the app, the error will disappear.

Comment: I try to clean solution and rebuild it, but this error does not disappear. after app running finish, if you wait for some minute after stop running app, this error appear again. for building my projects, please read our README.md and download `nuget` package from [linphone](https://www.linphone.org/releases/windows/sdk)

Comment: That might be an issue related to the Visual Studio. You could report this in https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/home

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT I report on https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/XDG0062-Type-MicrosoftUIXamlControls/10081031